# Change ui language based on windows user

Tags: windows-8.1

Is it possible to change the UI language of Windows 8.1 based on the currently logged in user?

Some backstory: I am from Germany and my girlfriend is from Scotland. She doesn't speak much German. I would like to use our new tablet in German, she would like to use it in English.

Comment: Do you have the capability to install language packs on the version of Windows 8.1 your using?

Comment: as long as it's not RT, the OP should be able to

Comment: @TD.512 - I am pretty sure even Windows RT had language packs.  I am more worried about single language editions of `Windows 8.1 Core`

Comment: @Ramhound both languages are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this is actually quite easy to implement, and can be done in 3 steps, but you need a multi-language edition of Windows

- Add the language
- Download the language pack
- Set your language

### Add the language

1. Swipe in from the right
2. Choose settings
3. Choose `Change PC Settings`
4. Choose `Time and Language`
5. Choose `Region and Language`
6. Choose `Add a Language` and choose the language you want

### Add the language pack

1. Pick the language you just chose
2. Choose `Options`
3. Choose `Download`

### Set the Language

1. Sign out of the current account
2. At the metro login, choose your language from the language bar next to the power button
3. Login with your chosen language

Comment: I don't feel like doing this myself to confirm, before I vote on the answer, this allows for two user profiles to have a different language pack and keyboard selected?  I know the last step will allow the user to select which language they want to use before they log into the account, and I think it is, close enough to what the user wants.  This is a good answer.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, but at the cost of you having to switch languages every time you login. This is also right according to Microsoft, so it should work.

Comment: @TD.512 for me it doesn't work. I have both German and English installed...

Comment: hm... according to MS, it should work

Comment: @TD.512 I just double checked English wasn't installed am installing it right now

Comment: ok, it didn't work. Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, Windows changes the language itself based on the user account. My girlfriend uses an UK Microsoft account I use a German Microsoft account.

So, it works :)